# JSON delete deletes attribute in source variable also

Tags: javascript, json

I have a small problem.

```
var template = data;
delete template.candidates;
```

The above code deletes `data.candidates` also.
Though I can solve it by some other logic. But I need the actual reason behind it and proper solution for this (not workaround).

Thanks in advance

Comment: You will have to make a copy of the object - have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/most-elegant-way-to-clone-a-javascript-object

Comment: See [Is JavaScript a pass-by-reference or pass-by-value language?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default `=` only creates reference of Object. In order to clone (which is requirement for you), you can do following

ES2015 (ES6) -

```
var template = Object.assign({}, data);
```

ES5 -

```
var template = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
```

Both option will clone the object in new variable called `template`. Now the next operation will just delete data from template keeping `data` intact.

Comment: Thanks @Bikas, that helped

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you are passing a reference to `data` to the variable `template`. An easy way to solve this "problem" is to clone the object by doing something like this:

`var template = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))`

Answer (score 1):

When you assign a Object to a variable, the variable doesn't actually "contain" the Object (like it is the case with an integer), the variable just contains a reference to the Object.
So by assigning `var template = data` you're not actually copying `data` into `template`, you're just copying the reference to the Object `template` is referencing. Therefore, you now have two variables, referencing the same Object and therefore doing anything with any of those variables, will affect the same Object.
So the solution to this, would be to actually clone the Object from `data` to `template`

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a copy of the object into your template var :

```js
var data = {
  candidates: [1, 2],
  test: [1]
};
var template = data.constructor();
for (var attr in data) {
  if (data.hasOwnProperty(attr)) template[attr] = data[attr];
}
delete template.candidates;
console.log(data, template);
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're running into is a problem with mutability, in your code data and template actually reference the same object and therefore changes to one will affect the other. You should make an effort to not mutate your variables and instead return a new object when you need to change something with them. You'll want to use the `Object.assign()` or spread operator. Another issue arises from the fact that there's not a proper way to delete object keys from JS the `delete` function you're using is actually quite slow.

```
const jsonFunction = input => {
    return {
        ...input,
        candidates: null,
        ...input
    }
};

const data = jsonFunction(template);
```

or alternatively with `Object.assign()`

```
const jsonFunction = input => {
    return Object.assign({}, input, candidates: null);
}

const data = jsonFunction(template);
```

This will return a new object and assign it to data, by handling it immutably it means you can deal with `data` and `template` without them affecting each other.